# Use layered requirements with project.optional-dependencies in pyproject.toml

Tags: pyproject.toml, pip-tools, pip-compile

I'd like to lock my dependencies tracked in `pyproject.toml` using [`pip-compile`](https://pip-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli/pip-compile/). How can I use the layered approach for development-only dependencies (quoting https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools#workflow-for-layered-requirements):

> If you have different environments that you need to install different but compatible packages for, then you can create layered requirements files and use one layer to constrain the other.
>
> For example, if you have a Django project where you want the newest `2.1` release in production and when developing you want to use the Django debug toolbar, then you can create two `*.in` files, one for each layer:
>
> ```ini
> # requirements.in
> django<2.2
> ```
>
> At the top of the development requirements `dev-requirements.in` you use `-c requirements.txt` to constrain the dev requirements to packages already selected for production in `requirements.txt`.
>
> ```ini
> # dev-requirements.in
> -c requirements.txt
> django-debug-toolbar<2.2
> ```

…but using dependencies tracked in `pyproject.toml` instead of `*.in` files? E.g.:

```ini
[project]
name = "hello"
version = "0.1.0"
dependencies = ["django<2.2"]

[project.optional-dependencies]
dev = ["django-debug-toolbar<2.2"]
```

I've tried adding `"-c requirements.txt"` to the optional dependencies, but `pip` complains that this is not PEP 508 compliant:

```
  ValueError: invalid pyproject.toml config: `project.optional-dependencies.dev[0]`.
  configuration error: `project.optional-dependencies.dev[0]` must be pep508
```

Is this supported or do I have to revert back to tracking my non-locked dependencies in `requirements.in` files?

Comment: `pip-compile --extra=dev --output-file=dev-requirements.txt pyproject.toml` and then `pip-compile --constraint=dev-requirements.txt --output-file=requirements.txt pyproject.toml`.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would try something like this:

```
pip-compile --extra=dev --output-file=dev-requirements.txt pyproject.toml
pip-compile --constraint=dev-requirements.txt --output-file=requirements.txt pyproject.toml
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tested this and I noticed a difference between this approach and the one from the [pip-tools readme](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools#workflow-for-layered-requirements): I added `requests` to `requirements.in` as well as `dependencies` in the `pyproject.toml`. Using the approach from the readme, `requests` and its dependencies do not appear in `dev-requirements.txt` but they do when using your approach. Do you know whether there is a significant difference between the two results and whether one is preferable to the other?

Comment: I do not know... I do not have time to try it myself... As a guess, maybe the commands were run in the incorrect order?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think this quite matches the concept of layered dependencies. it takes into account the dev extras alongside the dependencies. A truly layered approach would lock the dependencies alone, and then install the dev extras that are compatible with the locked dependenices.